# Filling colors of a stacked bar chart according to count instead of category (R/Excel)

Tags: r, excel, charts, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I want to create a stacked bar chart but I want the colors to be decided based on count. For instance, if I have 5 bars and each bar has 3 categories, the default way to color the bar chart is by category. (for instance, category 1 is red, category 2 is blue and category 3 is green). However, what I want is: if for bar 1, category 1 has the highest count, that would be red. Similarly, if for bar 2, category 3 has the highest count, I would want category 3 of the second bar to be colored red. Is there any way for me to do this? I can use R/Excel/Numbers/any other software.

This is what I currently have, and I want the color to be dictated by frequency(almost like a heatmap)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is straightforward in R.

If we have some data like this:

```r
set.seed(69)
df <- data.frame(category = sample(LETTERS, 200, TRUE))
```

We can do:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = category)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = ..count..), color = "black") +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("forestgreen", "gold", "red"))
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

It seems from the OP's supplementary information that the data is something like this:

```r
set.seed(69)
data <- data.frame(Question = rep(LETTERS[1:5], each = 5),
                   Response = rep(c("Strongly disagree", "Disagree", "Neutral",
                                  "Agree", "Strongly agree"), 5),
                   Frequency = as.vector(replicate(5, {
                                x <- sample(10:30, 5, TRUE); x / sum(x)})))
```

In which case, we could do something like this:

```r
ggplot(data = data, aes(y = Question, x = Frequency)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = Frequency)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = stringr::str_wrap(Response, 10)), 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("forestgreen", "gold", "red"))
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

A further request by the OP...

```r
ggplot(data = data, aes(y = Question, x = Frequency)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = Question, alpha = Frequency)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = stringr::str_wrap(Response, 10)), 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("deepskyblue4", "forestgreen", "gold", 
                                "orange", "red"),
                    name = "Question") +
  scale_alpha_continuous(guide = "none") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Would this also work with a stacked bar chart? Because right now, I have the following code: `ggplot() + geom_bar(aes(y = Question, x = Frequency, fill = Response), data = data,
                    stat="identity")`. Since I'm already using fill to color in the categories, can I have two fills?. I've updated the question to include a picture of what I have currently

Comment: @KartikShah see my update. I have also added text labels, but these could be removed by removing the `geom_text` call

Comment: This is amazing, thank you so much! Just one final question: is it possible to have the colors scaled for each question, instead of the overall frequency?